# Open a Powerpoint file in Presenter mode

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

I can open a Powperpoint file in directly in slideshow mode with this :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pptProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pptProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\MyPres.pptx";
pptProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
pptProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
pptProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "show"; // to open the slideshow
pptProcess.Start();
```

Now Powerpoint allows us to see our notes and slideshow in same time, it's the presenter mode.
So, I want to open a presentation directly in this mode.
I've tried differents "verbs" (StartInfo.Verb), differents arguments (StartInfo.Arguments) but  I didn't have a solution.

Do you have a solution for me ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint stores a flag in the registry to indicate whether it should show presentations in presenter view or not. For example, for PowerPoint 2010, it's in:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options

The value is a DWORD named UseMonMgr

You could set it to 1 before starting PowerPoint. Changing the registry after PowerPoint has started will have no effect.

Or once PPT is open, you can set the presentation object's SlideShowSettings.ShowPresenterView to true.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I had already modify the registry and your solution uses a Powerpoint Interop. We can't use it. We have to open Powepoint via a new Process.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I've only suggested modifying the registry, nothing to do with PowerPoint Interop.

Comment: SlideShowSettings.ShowPresenterView is a property for interop [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slideshowsettings.showpresenterview(v=office.14).aspx)
I have to use System.Diagnostics.Process to start a process of Powerpoint, and I can not access to the property SlideShowSettings.ShowPresenterView.

Comment: Re-read my answer then. Ignore the last line and read the rest.