# Opening PowerPoint in Presenter Mode via Process.Start() in C#

Tags: c#, process, powerpoint

I'm looking for a way to open up a PowerPoint in C# in Presenter View (the multi-screen view in which the presentation is in presentation mode on one screen and has speaker notes on the other screen) by creating a new process. I've tried starting the `Process` with an `/s` argument, but that will only bring up the PowerPoint in slide show mode (i.e. the presentation is on both screens).

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.FileName = "POWERPNT.EXE";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", "/s ", filePath);
process.Start();
```

I've also tried altering the registry value in which the option to set Presenter View is stored, but that doesn't seem to have any effect when opening from a `Process`. I know that using the `Interop` library is an option here, but I would prefer to use a `Process` for a couple reasons. Does anyone know how to open a PowerPoint in Presenter View via `Process.Start()`?

Comment: Did you change the correct version of the registry key: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24806318/578411

Comment: I believe so (that's the question I originally learned about the registry from), but I can't seem to open it in Presenter View even if that default value is set.